# The ways to keep appropriate language for loadable data

Tags: android, rest, multilingual

I have app that supports multilanguage. Besides UI and internal resources it has feature to load some data by RESTFUL API from the server and keep it localy for the future use. App makes call and receive data in a language that is currently in use by user.

What is the best way to update loaded data if user changes language? Currently my app asks a user if he wants to reload data in a new language on "yes" app fetches all data from the server with a new language, on "no" keeps the current one.

The googlish way is to keep all translation (UI,resources etc) for the supported langs within the app so may be the correct way is to load and keep data from server for all supported languages ?

**UPDATE**:
The loaded data is some kind of manual and it is rarely changed.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading all languages supported and caching them in the application for every data component may be excessive if you have a significant amount of them scattered across the application. If you are only allowing the user to change the language of the application in a specific Settings page, then you could set some trigger to automatically reload data that is not I18N whenever the User next encounters it, which seems to be a more logical and data saving behaviour.

Bare in mind that, for every new language you support, if you were to store everything locally, you are essentially adding an entire new copy of all your data in a space-constrained device, which is not really a wise choice at any time.

Comment: I understand the downsides of loading data for all supported languages and currently, as I wrote, the app just reloads data. Need practical advices how this problem can be solved optimally. Btw the size of app plus loaded data is not exceeded 30 megs so in my opinion its not a big deal to load a few more megs.